# Handling optional parser rules in ANTLR Listener

Tags: listener, antlr4

As an exercise I am trying to write a listener that can convert some pascal code into JavaScript. Is it possible to make this listener function behave differently for the program header depending on whether or not identifierList is used?

Listener function:

```
class PascalListenerImpl extends pascalBaseListener {

STGroup stg = new STGroupFile("./pascal.stg");
String programName;
@Override
public void enterProgram(pascalParser.ProgramContext ctx) {
    List<ParseTree> values = ctx.children;
    ArrayList<String> valueNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    programName = ctx.programHeading().getChild(1).getText();
    for (int i = 3; i<ctx.getChildCount(); i+=)
    ST st = stg.getInstanceOf("enterProgram")
    st.add("v", programName);

}
```

Grammar rules:

```
programHeading
    : 'PROGRAM' identifier (LPAREN identifierList RPAREN)? SEMI
    | 'UNIT' identifier SEMI
  ;

identifierList
    : identifier ( COMMA identifier )*
  ;
```

string template:

```
enterProgram(v, values) ::= "var <v> = function <v>(<values; seperator=", ") {"
```

Comment: Well... You have access to the `ProgramContext`, therefore you can do whatever you want with it. BTW try to avoid things like `getChild(1)`, the context is typed and there is an accessor for `identifier` inside.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how do I make use of this accessor?

Comment: It should be something like `ctx.programHeading().identifier` or `ctx.programHeading().getIdentifier()` (I don't know, I mainly use the C# version).

Comment: I have a rule like:
   
   something   : DIRECTIVE XDEF ID ( ',' ID )* 
     ;

And I'm trying to get the list of ID's into an array in my listener.
I believe this is similar, and I recall reading how to do it.  It seems like a common enough thing to do that there should be an example.
Once I figure out how to do it, (assuming I succeed), I will share my answer here to see if it will help others.